# AWS Access from HELM Charts

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault, aws-secrets-manager

**Scenario:**
I am running application into kubernetes and deploying using HELM charts my env files are in AWS secret Manager and i want to populate env from InitContainers.
I have a python scripts that actually pulls secrets from AWS secret manager and create env files but this requires AWS access (I have created Role that specifically allow AWS Secret Manager)

Problem is i don't want to open AWS access in plain text in helm charts i am looking for a secure way to provide AWS access

**Possible Solutions:**
I should set environment in HELM Charts so Init containers can assume role and execute the python script

I can use Hashicorp Vault and can fetch secret from there

**Issue**

- I dont want to put any access in my HELM charts
- If i use hashicorp vault then i need to supply unseal key or user token in HELM charts

I don't want to reveal any information in plain text if anyone has better way of doing this please let me know

Thanks

**Issue**

- I dont want to put any access in my HELM charts
- If i use hashicorp vault then i need to supply unseal key or user token in HELM charts

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EKS you can [federate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) the access so that containers can assume a role inside the cluster (your python app).

Otherwise you could store your secrets as k8s secrets and encrypt these (EKS does this easily if you configure it)

You could mount secrets from the secretmanager directly via a CSI [driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/manage-secrets.html)

You could also use other solutions like Mozilla sops.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution what i did is i assigned role to my worker nodes that can access AWS secret manager by this i don't need to expose my Keys in init containers

```
module "secret_manager_readonly" {
source                      = "../modules/v1.3.7/iam"
  create                      = var.secret_manager_readonly_create
  this_policy_name            = "secret_manager_readonly"
  policy_description          = "secret_manager_readonly"
  this-json-tpl               = var.secret_manager_readonly_policy_json
  this-stsrole-json-filename  = var.this-stsrole-json-filename
  profile_name                = "SecretManagerProfile"
  tags                        = var.tags       
}
```

Role that i consume in worker

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attachment" {
  for_each = toset([
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy",
    data.aws_iam_policy.secret_manager_readonly.arn
  ])

  role       = module.atom_iam_eks_node.role_name
  policy_arn = each.value
  depends_on = [
    module.atom_iam_eks_node,
    data.aws_iam_policy.secret_manager_readonly
  ]
}
```